# Loop through array then compare current object to string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I'm trying to iterate through an `NSArray` and check if an `objectAtIndex` is equal to a `string`.

```
NSLog(@"%@", myArray) // 3 items. 1 of them is "a"
for (id object in myArray)
{
    NSLog(@"What"); // 3 times
    if ([object isEqual:@"a"]) {
        NSLog(@"Hello"); // Never gets executed
    }
}
```

The problem is, the `NSLog` in the if statement never gets executed?

**Edit**

```
(
        (
        a
    ),
        (
        01
    ),
        (
        a
    ),
        (
        03
    )
)
```

When I set it to `isEqualToString`, I get this error:

```
2015-03-30 14:42:54.206 MyApp[1575:50954] -[__NSArrayM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe721ce3bf0
2015-03-30 14:42:54.215 MyApp[1575:50954] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe721ce3bf0'
```

Comment: Show us the full log output.

Comment: `isEqualToString:` is the better choice, but `isEqual:` should still work. Please post the log so we can see what's actually in `myArray`. I don't think `@"a"` is in there.

Comment: I'll post the output.

Comment: If both objects are strings, `isEqual:` and `isEqualToString:` should both work; the latter is a performance optimization.

Comment: Just updated my question

Comment: And there's your issue. You have an array of arrays of strings. Not an array of strings.

Comment: Thanks everyone!! And don't forget to up vote the question if you like it!! lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have an array that contains three sub-arrays, each of which contain, what is presumably, a single string. You can tell this because of the extra ()'s around the strings in the log output, and by the fact that it's telling you that you tried to send a selector to `__NSArrayM`.

Here is a quick fix:

```
NSLog(@"%@", myArray) // 3 items. 1 of them is "a"
for (NSArray *array in myArray)
{
    NSLog(@"What"); // 3 times
    if ([array.firstObject isEqualToString:@"a"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Hello"); // Never gets executed
    }
}
```

But as others have pointed out you probably want to use `isEqualToString:` since it will be more performant.

You may also want to reconsider the code that is generating this nested array structure, or the schema that you're using in general, because it seems... unnecessary. Without further information there's not much to be done.

Comment: Thanks!! This may be out of the scope of the question, but here is the array that I initialized: `NArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.ingredientsDBManager loadDataFromDB:amountQuery]];` I used appCoda to implement SQLite.

Comment: The DB is giving it back to you the way you see it above.  You should open a new question if you want help with that; I don't know much about appCoda.